# freeglut GLUT_MULTISAMPLE very slow on Intel HD Graphics 3000

Tags: opengl, glut

I just picked up a new Lenovo Thinkpad that comes with Intel HD Graphics 3000.  I'm finding that my old freeglut apps, which use GLUT_MULTISAMPLE, are running at 2 or 3 fps as opposed to the expected 60fps.  Even the freeglut example 'shapes' runs this slow.

If I disable GLUT_MULTISAMPLE from shapes.c (or my app) things run quickly again.

I tried multisampling on glfw (using GLFW_FSAA - or whatever that hint is called), and I think it's working fine.  This was with a different app (glgears).  glfw is triggering Norton Internet Security, which things it's malware so keeps removing .exes... but that's another problem...  my interest is with freeglut.

I wonder if the algorithm that freeglut uses to choose a pixel format is tripping up on this card, whereas glfw is choosing the right one.

Has anyone else come across something like this?  Any ideas?

Comment: Thats probably bug in freeglut, or glfw or Intel drivers :/ glgears is tooo simple to judge impact on performance and there should be some impact, as Multisampling mean more job for gpu.

Answer (score 1):

That glfw triggeres Norton is a bug in Nortons virus definition. If it's still the case with the latest definitions, send them your glfw dll/app so they can fix it. Same happens on Avira and they are working on it (have already confirmed that it's a false positive).

As for the HD3000, that's quite a weak GPU, what resolution is your app and how many samples are you using? Maybe the amount of framebuffer memory gets to high for the little guy?